# Coronavirus package latest data

Tags: r

Hi I am looking to see how to update the dataset for the `coronavirus` R-package.

How do I go about to that?

If I test out below, the latest date is February 16th:

```
library(coronavirus)
data(coronavirus)
max(coronavirus$date)
[1] "2020-02-16"
```

Comment: I found this link today.   https://towardsdatascience.com/a-short-review-of-covid-19-data-sources-ba7f7aa1c342, Listed are some other potential options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should install the package from github instead of from cran. The [github package](https://github.com/RamiKrispin/coronavirus) is updated regularly. Cran is not meant for daily updates.